# java.. My array list[] is storing the same value again and again

Tags: java

// this code has problem
public class DirectionList {

```
private static Direction[] list;// this array is creating problems
private int next = 0;
private final int SIZE = 8;
public DirectionList()
{
     list = new Direction[SIZE];// set array size
}

public void addDirection(Direction d) {
    list[next++] = d;// problematic line
```

// in this line, the code should input new data in the given index of the array. but the previous data is //erased and new data is overwritten in all index's... suppose I put a in list[0] and then put b in //list[1].. then both list[0] and list[1] becomes b

```
    }

}

public String toString()
{
    String result = "{";
    
    for(int i = 0; i < list.length; i++)
    {
        if( list[i] == null) {
            result+= "" + i;
        }
        else {
            result += list[i];//list[0].toString();
            
            if(list[i] != null) {
                
                result+= ",";
                }
            }
    }
    
    
    result+= "}";
    return result;
}
```

}

//// the code below is another code for testing the output of above code

public class DirectionListTest {
public static void main(String[] args) {

```
    try {

        d.addDirection(new Direction(1, 0));//5
        s = d.toString();

        System.out.println("Test 1 (should be {<down>} ): " + s);

        d.addDirection(new Direction(0, -1));
        d.addDirection(new Direction(-1, 1));//6
        s = d.toString();

        System.out.println("Test 2 (should be {<down>,<left>,<up right>} ): " + s);

    } catch (NoSuchMethodError e) {
        System.out.println("Tests failed: Method not named correctly.");

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Tests failed: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Well, your storage array is `static`, so you can only ever have one instance of it. Remove that part, and use one instance of your list class per separate list you want to store

Comment: @Rogue thank you very much. I am new in java. I removed static but it is not working.. can you please help me with the second part of your comment?

Comment: @the_ahnafpiash, can you please show us the structure of "Direction"? Rogue ... there could be other reasons!!

Comment: @Jaja sure... I can show you... here it is https://pastebin.com/BDSg4zAb

Comment: remove all the ```static``` properties and methods from the ```Direction```  class.

Comment: @the_ahnafpiash, static there means: for all Object of the Class, the static properties are "same". This is about the idea behind static, you can read more here https://www.dummies.com/programming/java/what-is-the-static-keyword-in-java/